# iOS Perform segue after dismissing view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

My app stores user configurations with two different view controllers. The first is only presented when the create a new configuration, which is the name of the configuration. The second is the configuration itself which is normally brought up by accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath

Is it possible that when they dismiss the first view controller where they set the name:

```
[self.delegate addViewerViewController:self didFinishAddingItem:viewer];
```

That it presents the configuration view controller straight away without having to tap? Normally this is called by

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    nameAtAccessoryIndex = [viewerKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"EditSettings" sender:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: have you tried calling it in `-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` of the first ViewController?

Comment: Does it not require an indexPath though? Or it won't know which configuration to load

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `performSegueWithIdentifier:` improperly. Your sender should be `self`.

Add `prepareForSegue:` to your view controller, and set `viewer` on `segue.destinationViewController` inside it.